# Error with a populated SelectListItem when posting data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, selectlist

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm trying to populate a dropdownlist from my database doing this :

My models :

```
public class AppointmentViewModel
{

    public string DisplayDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }


    public MedecinViewModel Medecin { get; set; }

    public SuggestionViewModel Suggestion { get; set; }

}

public class MedecinViewModel
{
    public int MedecinId { get; set; }

    public String MedecinNom { get; set; }
}
```

My dropdownlist :

```
<div class="editor-field">
                 @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Medecin.MedecinId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Medecins, "Choisissez un médecin")
            </div>
```

My controller :

```
ViewBag.Medecins = new SelectList(context.DBMedecins, "MedecinId", "FullName");
```

It seems like after doing my **post action**, something's wrong and I'm getting the following error message :

The ViewData item that has the key 'Medecin.MedecinId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'?

What's wrong with that?

EDIT : My GET and POST Controllers

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ConfirmAppointment(string interval)
    {
        context = new SchedulingDataClassesDataContext();

        ViewBag.Medecins = new SelectList(context.DBMedecins, "MedecinId", "FullName");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ConfirmAppointment(AppointmentViewModel avm)
    {
        context = new SchedulingDataClassesDataContext();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //logical code
        }

        return View(avm);
    }
```

Comment: Would help if you could show us your Controller code (i.e. GET and POST).

Comment: @Belogix here you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to populate `SelectList` again in `ViewBag` in post action, because after post action it again renders the view but `Viewbag.Medecins` is not set in post action so it becomes null as `ViewBag` scope is from action to view only and after that it becomes null again :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ConfirmAppointment(AppointmentViewModel avm)
    {
        context = new SchedulingDataClassesDataContext();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //logical code
        }
        ViewBag.Medecins = new SelectList(context.DBMedecins, "MedecinId", "FullName");
        return View(avm);
    }
```